# consistency of floating point division

Tags: python, floating-point

It is well known that floating point values cannot exactly represent every decimal value.  Thus, the floating point value for 1/3 is not exactly 1/3.  For this reason, it is generally inadvisable to compare floating point values directly.

However, in this application, I am trying to determine if two fractions a / b and c / d are equivalent.  If they are, then there exist integers e and f such that `a * e = c * f` and `b * e = d * f`.  Assume a, b, c, d, e, f are all positive integers which can be represented exactly in a floating point value.

**In practice, simply comparing `a/b` to `c/d` worked, but is it guaranteed to work?  Is there something within Python and/or IEEE-754 that would guarantee such a scheme to work?**

Example code (that shows this scheme works for a reasonable number of values):

```
a = 1.0
b = 3.0
for c in xrange(1, 999):
    assert a / b == (a * c) / (b * c)
```

If this is not guaranteed, is there a counterexample with values a, b, c, d such that a/b = c/d (in math) but Python fails to compare `a / b == c / d`?  Again, these are all positive integers which Python can exactly represent in its floating point value.

Comment: That is not the only type of counter-example; you could also have a/b is *not* equal to c/d, but `a/b == c/d`.

Comment: You've answered your own question inside your question.

Comment: @Scott Hunter, good point, false positives would also be of interest.  False negatives are of more interest, however.

Comment: Is this the problem you want to solve: Given floating-point values a, b, c, and d, determine whether a/b is mathematically equal to c/d, without effect from floating-point arithmetic?

Answer (score 5):

IEEE 754 division is specified to behave as if you computed the exact result of the division and then rounded the exact result. If `a/b` and `c/d` have the same value in exact arithmetic, then since IEEE 754 rounding is consistent and deterministic, `a/b` and `c/d` must have the same result in IEEE 754 floating point.

This only holds if `a/b` and `c/d` really do have the same value in exact arithmetic, though. Rounding error in `a`, `b`, `c`, or `d` can throw this off. Also, the converse doesn't hold; if `a/b == c/d` in floating point, that doesn't mean `a/b` and `c/d` are equal in exact arithmetic.

---

Rather than dealing with floating-point rounding, why not stick to integers?

```
a*d == b*c
```

can be done in unrounded integer arithmetic. Alternatively, why not use an exact rational type?

```
from fractions import Fraction

Fraction(a, b) == Fraction(c, d)
```

Answer (score 2):

By specification of division in IEEE-754, if *a*/*b* = *c*/*d*, then `a/b == c/d`, provided that the operations in `a/b == c/d` are evaluated as specified in IEEE-754 using one floating-point format. (Python does not make this guarantee; it inherits the floating-point behavior of whatever platform it is implemented on, and IEEE-754 behavior is not universally guaranteed.) This is because IEEE-754 specifies that the result is the exact mathematical result rounded to the nearest representable value (according to the applicable rounding mode). Since the mathematical results are identical for *a*/*b* and *c*/*d*, the computed results are identical.

However, `a/b == c/d` does not imply *a*/*b* = *c*/*d*. A counterexample is that `1 / (0x1p53-1)` and `1 / (0x1p53-2)` both produce 1.11022302462515678694266454965700950366517665087069677287701097156968899071216583251953125 • 10<sup>−16</sup> (in hexadecimal floating-point, 0x1.0000000000001p-53).

Answer (score 1):

Well, I tried a few random numbers and found this. But as @user2357112 points out, this more due to a deficiency of the test than a good example.

Leaving this here to demonstrate the fact.

```
a = 653543435456556.0
b = 3.0

for c in range(1, 999):
    assert a / b == (a * c) / (b * c), (c, a / b - (a * c) / (b * c))

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AssertionError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-128-405615b37738> in <module>()
      2 b = 3.0
      3 for c in range(1, 999):
----> 4     assert a / b == (a * c) / (b * c), (c, a / b - (a * c) / (b * c))
      5 

AssertionError: (57, -0.03125)
```

Comment: This fails due to rounding error in `a * c`, though. After that rounding error, the fractions don't have the same result in exact arithmetic. This is more of a flaw in the questioner's test than an inconsistency in division.